# In which table should I save the value of system_settings_form in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, configuration

I am using Drupal 7 and creating a form with some fields like position.

```
function mycustom_form($form, &$form_state){
  $form = array();
  $form['position'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('Position for the magnifier'),
   '#options' => array('left' => 'Left', 'right' => 'Right','up'=>'Up','down'=>'Down'),
   '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

When I click on save with any position selected, these values are saved. So I am not getting where these values are saved and how to use these values in a JavaScript file... I am saving these values in a database.

Answer (score 6):

If you use system_settings_form function your data will be saved in 'variable' table.
To get saved data you may use [variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) function.

To show saved value in form

```
       function mycustom_form($form, &$form_state){
         $form = array();
         $form['position'] = array(
           '#type' => 'textfield',
           '#title' => t('Position for the magnifier'),
           '#options' => array('left' => 'Left', 'right' => 'Right','up'=>'Up','down'=>'Down'),
           '#default_value' => variable_get('position', ''),
           '#required' => TRUE,
         );

         return system_settings_form($form);
       }
```

If you want to use saved data from your form in the javascript, you may use next code

```
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('position' => variable_get('position', ''))), 'setting');
```

Then this data will be available in javascript in `Drupal.settings.myModule.position` variable

Comment: I also need to use this position value (right/left etc) in javascript file.